Converting FHIR Json to Google proto generated model
We have the FHIR JSON model which needs to be serialized using protobuf but we are not able to serialize it as the JSON is not getting parsed to the generated google fhir models.
https://github.com/google/fhir
FHIR JSON:
{
  "resourceType" : "Bundle",
  "id" : "bundle-transaction",
  "meta" : {
    "lastUpdated" : "2014-08-18T01:43:30Z"
  },
  "type" : "transaction",
  "entry" : [{
    "fullUrl" : "urn:uuid:61ebe359-bfdc-4613-8bf2-c5e300945f0a",
    "resource" : {
      "resourceType" : "Patient",
      "text" : {
        "status" : "generated",
        "div" : "<div xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">Some narrative</div>"
      },
      "active" : true,
      "name" : [{
        "use" : "official",
        "family" : "Chalmers",
        "given" : ["Peter",
        "James"]
      }],
      "gender" : "male",
      "birthDate" : "1974-12-25"
    },
    "request" : {
      "method" : "POST",
      "url" : "Patient"
    }
  },
  {
    "fullUrl" : "urn:uuid:88f151c0-a954-468a-88bd-5ae15c08e059",
    "resource" : {
      "resourceType" : "Patient",
      "text" : {
        "status" : "generated",
        "div" : "<div xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">Some narrative</div>"
      },
      "identifier" : [{
        "system" : "http:/example.org/fhir/ids",
        "value" : "234234"
      }],
      "active" : true,
      "name" : [{
        "use" : "official",
        "family" : "Chalmers",
        "given" : ["Peter",
        "James"]
      }],
      "gender" : "male",
      "birthDate" : "1974-12-25"
    },
    "request" : {
      "method" : "POST",
      "url" : "Patient",
      "ifNoneExist" : "identifier=http:/example.org/fhir/ids|234234"
    }
  },
  {
    "fullUrl" : "http://example.org/fhir/Patient/123",
    "resource" : {
      "resourceType" : "Patient",
      "id" : "123",
      "text" : {
        "status" : "generated",
        "div" : "<div xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">Some narrative</div>"
      },
      "active" : true,
      "name" : [{
        "use" : "official",
        "family" : "Chalmers",
        "given" : ["Peter",
        "James"]
      }],
      "gender" : "male",
      "birthDate" : "1974-12-25"
    },
    "request" : {
      "method" : "PUT",
      "url" : "Patient/123"
    }
  },
  {
    "fullUrl" : "urn:uuid:74891afc-ed52-42a2-bcd7-f13d9b60f096",
    "resource" : {
      "resourceType" : "Patient",
      "text" : {
        "status" : "generated",
        "div" : "<div xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">Some narrative</div>"
      },
      "identifier" : [{
        "system" : "http:/example.org/fhir/ids",
        "value" : "456456"
      }],
      "active" : true,
      "name" : [{
        "use" : "official",
        "family" : "Chalmers",
        "given" : ["Peter",
        "James"]
      }],
      "gender" : "male",
      "birthDate" : "1974-12-25"
    },
    "request" : {
      "method" : "PUT",
      "url" : "Patient?identifier=http:/example.org/fhir/ids|456456"
    }
  },
  {
    "fullUrl" : "http://example.org/fhir/Patient/123a",
    "resource" : {
      "resourceType" : "Patient",
      "id" : "123a",
      "text" : {
        "status" : "generated",
        "div" : "<div xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">Some narrative</div>"
      },
      "active" : true,
      "name" : [{
        "use" : "official",
        "family" : "Chalmers",
        "given" : ["Peter",
        "James"]
      }],
      "gender" : "male",
      "birthDate" : "1974-12-25"
    },
    "request" : {
      "method" : "PUT",
      "url" : "Patient/123a",
      "ifMatch" : "W/\"2\""
    }
  },
  {
    "request" : {
      "method" : "DELETE",
      "url" : "Patient/234"
    }
  },
  {
    "request" : {
      "method" : "DELETE",
      "url" : "Patient?identifier=123456"
    }
  },
  {
    "fullUrl" : "urn:uuid:79378cb8-8f58-48e8-a5e8-60ac2755b674",
    "resource" : {
      "resourceType" : "Parameters",
      "parameter" : [{
        "name" : "coding",
        "valueCoding" : {
          "system" : "http://loinc.org",
          "code" : "1963-8"
        }
      }]
    },
    "request" : {
      "method" : "POST",
      "url" : "http://hl7.org/fhir/ValueSet/$lookup"
    }
  },
  {
    "request" : {
      "method" : "GET",
      "url" : "Patient?name=peter"
    }
  },
  {
    "request" : {
      "method" : "GET",
      "url" : "Patient/12334",
      "ifNoneMatch" : "W/\"4\"",
      "ifModifiedSince" : "2015-08-31T08:14:33+10:00"
    }
  }]
}

And the code that we have used to serialize it is as shown below:
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Load the FHIR JSON bundle
        //FHIR JSON from the above 
        string fhirJson = File.ReadAllText("REFER THE ABOVE FHIR JSON");
 
        // Parse the FHIR JSON bundle
        var jsonParser = new JsonParser(JsonParser.Settings.Default.WithIgnoreUnknownFields(true));
        var bundle = jsonParser.Parse<Bundle>(fhirJson);
 
        // Serialize the bundle to Protobuf
        byte[] protobufData;
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bundle.WriteTo(memoryStream);
            protobufData = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
 
        // Save the Protobuf data to a file
        File.WriteAllBytes("fhir_bundle.protobuf", protobufData);
 
        Console.WriteLine("FHIR bundle converted to Protobuf and saved to fhir_bundle.protobuf");
    }

We are using the R4 version.
This is resulting in an exception Google.Protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException.

Drive-by comment since my interest is piqued by protocol-buffers but it appears that you are using the generic JSON parser and you cannot because "we need custom parsers"

Hi @DazWilkin , JSON parser is not generic it is from Google.Protobuf.JsonParser, do you mean we need to use specific parser with language dependency ?
I see that we have parsers for C++, GO, Java but not for C# do you have anything for C# so that we can parse this FHIR JSON in C#?

You need to use a specific parser per the documentation link that I included in my comment. You will need one for C#

Yes you are right @DazWilkin. I had raised a issue in the google fhir repo and I got the reply from the author saying that they are not supporting C# parsers at this moment.
https://github.com/google/fhir/issues/445
Do you have any repo link where they are doing this, I mean C# parsers for google fhir models  for serialization?
